# Minimum bar for an answer not to be classified a 'link only answer'

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers

While in the low quality post deleting bad answers just now, I saw this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41540205/445131

[image]

The answer isn't spam, it answers the question perfectly.  I checked out the link, and I'm thinking "wow", this is the best plugin I've seen for sublime, I tested it, it works.  I edited and upvoted the answer thinking it was good, but then a 140k moderator came around and deleted it.

Is it deleted because it's a link only answer?

Is it because sublime isn't open source and free plugins to non free software are considered bad?

Or could it be muscle memory from a mod deleting link only answers from low rep users without considering the greatness of the content?

How might I have changed the post so that a 140k rep mod doesn't come around and give it the thumbs-down of smite?

Comment: I think the main problem here begins with the question itself which is basically a tool request. Such question usually draw a link only answers. The problem with the answer is that it doesn't provide an example of actual usage or other related things. A link only answer could be helpful for an expert user such as yourself but in general ins't very helpful. IMO, it is similar to the "Try this:" answers which solve perfectly the problem but are not helpful for future users because they don't actually understand what the code does and can't generalize the solution to similar situations.

Comment: Why bring up rep? Rep has nothing to do with any of the actions here. If Jon Skeet had posted that answer, it'd have been deleted as well.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: It was a good tool, but stackoverflow isn't a place for link only toolset recommendations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it deleted because it's a link only answer?

Impossible to know without asking meagar personally, but I'd guess that yes.

> Is it because sublime isn't open source and free plugins to non free
>   software are considered bad?

Moderators don't take topicality into account when choosing whether to delete an answer. (Other than deleting if it's blatantly not addressing the question at all). Merely being a link only answer is sufficient for deletion already.

> Or could it be muscle memory from a mod deleting link only answers
>   from low rep users without considering the greatness of the content?

Link only answers always get deleted, regardless of the rep of the user that they come from. The answer you linked to would probably have been better off as a comment.

> How might I have changed the post so that a 140k rep mod doesn't come
>   around and give it the thumbs-down of smite?

Nothing you can do, it's a link only answer.

The litmus test for an answer (and whether it is link only) is if you removed the link, it still has to be an answer, which the one you linked to is (in my opinion) not.

Comment: I'm not seeing a massive difference between the deleted answer  and this one on that basis http://stackoverflow.com/a/16873475/73226

Comment: The statement that all link only answers get deleted is provably wrong.  I could provide tens of thousands of examples of high rep users who provide link only answers to very high quality content and tools and they stick around, some with hundreds of upvotes.  I'm the eleventh top user sitewide on stackoverflow for handling the low quality queue, so I know what I'm talking about.  There is hypocrisy in the interpretation of what is a link only answer and what isn't.  How much rep you have determines if your link only answer stays or goes.  The quality of the linked content also plays a role.

Comment: @EricLeschinski Correction, Link only answers provided _recently_. Some aren't deleted for historical / upvote reasons, I guess.

Comment: @EricLeschinski link only answers that have been flagged or otherwise brought to the attention of moderators get deleted, that doesn't happen to all of them though.

Comment: OP on the deleted answer here. I see the point made by the comment on my deleted answer. And I see the points made here and appreciate the discussion.

However, because it _is_ a tool request kind of question and the tool is well enough documented with gifs, and instructions, a link to the the tool's internet home seems like a reasonable answer.

More than that, it feels like the case where I was I'm back in school, being asked to make 20 pages out of my sufficient 6 page paper (so I make up BS to accommodate).

I'm happy to learn how to make higher quality content, and I love SO, though

Comment: @SteveMeisner The gist is ... tool request questions should be closed instead of answered. Link only answers are generally forbidden, and tool request questions are off topic because they tend to attract those.

Comment: I got to that question because I had the same one. None of the answers helped me, and after more research I found something that worked really well. I would have been glad to find my answer..So it would seem this is a philosophical issue.

Comment: @SteveMeisner It's just that ... Stack Overflow is focused mainly on very topical and technical Q/A, that means, as little opinion as possible and as much fact as possible. Tool recommendations always either attract spam or turn into a tool popularity contest in the answers. Stack decided to not allow these at all then. That's why they're supposed to be closed. I guess if you really ought to know the answer to such a question, you'll need to look elsewhere.